# Show that estimators are consistent and show which is more efficient

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have two independent binomial 
$X_1 =$ binomial $(n,p)$
and
$X_2 = $ binomial $(2n,p)$

we assume that $n$ is known but $p$ is an unknown parameter

I want to show that 
$P_1= 1/3n(X_1+X_2)$
and
$P_2= 1/2n(X_1+0.5X_2)$

are both consistent estimators.

I already know that $E(P_1)$ and $E(P_2) = p$ and are both unbiased estimators of p but how can I prove that they are consistent?

I think that I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting the same Variance for both estimators.

Var($P_1)$ and Var$(P_2) = p(1-p)$ which would make them both equally efficient.

Could someone please check my solution?

Comment: Why did you delete the entire body of the post? If you want to ask another question, do it in a separate post.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: It's called vandalism, and is one way to get banned from SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to show is that the variance of your estimator goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.
$$\textsf{Var}(P_1) = \textsf{Var}(\frac{1}{3n} (X_1 + X_2))  = \frac{1}{9n^2} [\textsf{Var}(X_1) + \textsf{Var}(X_2) ] $$
Using the variance of a binomial that is $\textsf{Var}(X) = np(1-p)$
$$\textsf{Var}(P_1)  = \frac{1}{9n^2} [np(1-p) + 2np(1-p) ] = \frac{3np(1-p)}{9n^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{3n} \rightarrow 0 $$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

More info could be found on this [YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oHP87KlZB8) on minute 00:40:23.

Comment: Thank you!The lecture is great. Very helpful.